# Can not install Ubuntu virutal machines on VirtualBox and VMware Player

Tags: virtualbox, 64-bit, virtualization, vmware-player

I have tried several times in several days to install Ubuntu (from 12.04 to 14.04 versions) on VirtualBox, but in vail. The problem I encounter is shown on the following picture where everything stacks on that step for several hours (I have been waiting for 6 hours as the longest period of waiting).

My host machine runs Windows 7 and I have a 64 bit processor.

[image]

Installation is however successful when I use VMware Player. However, the password I type for my session is never recognized after the installation, so I have to use the guest session only.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

I just noticed that on VirtualBox, during the preparation for installation, it shows that my VM is not connected to the internet (while my host machine is connected).

Comment: Have you verified the ISOs you are using have matching hash sums with those we know to be good?

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, absolutely

Comment: Explain what you mean by "never recognized" with regard to the password.  Also check your network connectivity - looks like you might have some weirdness in your network if it halts at retrieving files.  (Looks like it might be trying to update?)

Comment: @ThomasW. by *never recognized* I mean the password is always rejected (considered as a wrong one, whereas I am sure about it and reinstalled different versions several times. This concerns only VMware Player). About the network: on Vmware Player it installs well, so I wonder what could have to do with VirtualBox on this side. However, you may be right somehow. The network I am using is filtered by a proxy on which I have no control.

Comment: It sounds like the proxy might be causing issues.  Try installing again but unchecking the "Install updates" option at the prompt - it'll install the stuff from the CD but shouldn't pull  down updates.  It might try and pull a couple drivers if you need special ones, but I don't think it'll have to.

Comment: @ThomasW. Thank you, I am going to do what you asked me

Comment: In fact, by default it is unchecked

Comment: In the Virtual Box "Network" settings of your VM try with "Attached to `Bridged Adapter`" (and enable network adapter of course).

Comment: @Takkat Yes, but my problem is that I can not install the VM yet :)

Comment: Setting of a VM have to made **before** installing an OS.

Comment: @Takkat I want to kiss you :) I did what you said and it works (even the problem I had with VMware Player does not appear now). Could you explain me shortly what has this to do with the problem I had on VirtualBox ? (see picture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to properly install Ubuntu a working Internet connection is needed. In case the installer wants to download files it will stall in case it could not connect. When installing on bare metal the Ubuntu live session will already have drivers for most network adapters including wireless adapters to be able to connect.

This is different when installing in virtual machines, as these will make use of the host network for conntecting to the Internet. Therefore we will have to tell the virtual machine application to what network it should connect **before** we install Ubuntu. This is done in settings for a virtual machine we are about to create.

For Virtual Box this can be done from the Virtual Box Manager in the *Network* settings tab:

[image]
 <sup>Screenshot from: [Wifi card on an virtualbox's ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282018/wifi-card-on-an-virtualboxs-ubuntu)</sup>

- Tick to enable networking
- Choose the type of networking it is ***attached to*** (`Bridged` *vs.* `NAT`, or `Host Only`, see [Which type of VirtualBox networking should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95022/which-type-of-virtualbox-networking-should-i-use)). Choose a bridged adapter when unsure.
- Choose the ***name*** of the host network interface to connect to (e.g. `ethX` or `wlanX`).

Also see the follwing question for attaching to a wireless LAN:

- [Wireless Network in Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178804/wireless-network-in-virtualbox)