# Connecting ROS in VirtualBox, Ubuntu and MATLAB on Windows

Tags: virtualbox, matlab

I'm trying to connect ROS which is running on a virtual Ubuntu with VirtualBox with my Windows computer which is running the virtual machine.

I need to run MATLAB off of the Windows machine and ROS off of Ubuntu, but they need to be able to be connected, and I've been having substantial trouble with this. I need to be able to publish the ROS IP and get the VirtualBox network set up properly...

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the network on the VM (guest) as bridged, that means that it will use your physical network card (host) and it will get its own IP from the router.

More info in [What are the main differences between VirtualBox networking types?](https://askubuntu.com/a/95026/260379)

I also recommend you to configure the VM with a static IP (reference: [Linux basics: set a static IP on Ubuntu](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu)), so you can add it as hostname on hosts file in your Windows machine (reference: [Hosts file in Windows](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/hosts-file-in-windows)), in order to access it as a name like "rosvm" and not by IP.