# Having a hard time setting a static ip

Tags: networking

I am running a ubuntu server on VirtualBox, my host os Windows 10 and the guest os is ubuntu 14.04.5. I've been trying to get a static ip setup for a while now. I'm using it to run zabbix for testing purposes, but it won't ping anything and it can't resolve a host when trying to download packages.
This is my /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

and this is my resolv.conf file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong details for the static ip, but I used ipconfig on the command line in windows and I used the details from there, but used an ip address outside the range of the dhcp for my router.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the VM configured in bridged mode?

Comment: No it is not, I have tried having just NAT, and have also done Host-Only and NAT.

Comment: AFAIK you will need to use bridged mode if you want the VM to have an address in the same network segment as the host - see [Which type of VirtualBox networking should I use?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/95022/which-type-of-virtualbox-networking-should-i-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the virtual machine to use an IP address within the same IP subnet as the host, you need to edit the VM's Network Settings and change from the default NAT mode to Bridged Adapter mode:

[image: VirtualBox - bridged networking dialog]