# VirtualBox network configuration

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, internet, client

There is a host PC that runs VirtualBox. There are 3 Virtual Machines installed. An Ubuntu Server, an Ubuntu Desktop and a Windows 7. I have te be able to access the Ubuntu Server from a totally different PC. Not the host, not any of the guests, another one. So it has to get a fix IP. This Ubuntu Server has to function as a server in the virtual network. It has to be a DHCP and DNS server for the two other VMs. The two other VMs also have to access the internet, but across the Ubuntu Server. So that's the problem. I just have no idea what network cards and configuration file settings are needed to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Using a virtual machine for such things can at times become complicated. Easiest approach is to use bridged networking for the server.

See [Which type of VirtualBox networking should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95022/which-type-of-virtualbox-networking-should-i-use)

You can use NAT, and there is a graphical tool to configure NAT in the advanced options under NAT. Using NAT is also known as port forwarding, so the configuration is similar to how one would confiugre a router. Here teh virtualbox network configuration is using NAT and port forwarding your services.

> To configure Port Forwarding you can use the graphical Port Forwarding
>   editor which can be found in the Network Settings dialog for Network
>   Adaptors configured to use NAT. Here you can map host ports to guest
>   ports to allow network traffic to be routed to a specific port in the
>   guest.

see https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat

Graphical tutorial here : http://ask.xmodulo.com/access-nat-guest-from-host-virtualbox.html

NOTE: Link given as I could not see how to copy-paste the graphical pictures here as there is not a direct link to pics.

General pics

[image: Advanced options]

[image: Port forwarding]

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point the "server" should be equipped with two network interfaces: one external which you would bridge to the host's network interface and one internal (NAT). The two clients should have only one network interface (NAT).

That way your "server" would have access to the internet through the external bridged network interface and you could set it up to act as a router/gateway for the two clients.

Comment: That is not necessary as the internal network is already firewalled via the router ("internal network") and the server is already using NAT. You are you are making the situation even more complex by having 2 network interfaces. Better to continue to use NAT and configure it properly which can be done with the VBox graphical tool.

Comment: But he has already this setup with NAT in all VM machines.

Comment: So why does the server need to be equipped with two interfaces ? The OP has not listed a singer service that requires more then one virtual network interface.

Comment: And the question is clearly this: "The server has to access the internet on its own, while the clients have to access the internet across the server. ". So, your answer doesn't answer the question but something else.

Comment: No one would use internal networking. See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_internal . It is all configured through the vbox interface without the need for a second interface on the server.

Comment: This is your assumption :) What about someone who want to learn how to setup a gateway using ubuntu?

Comment: The setup is the same, just using the vbox tool to configure the networking, nothing else changes.

Comment: OK and that way he will never learn how to setup a linux server to do so. On the other hand, he will learn how to do it only with Virtual Box machines :\

Comment: Ie intead of learning how to use iptables, he will learn how to user the graphical tool that is provided by the VirtualBox for port forwarding.

Comment: The OP is not asking to use IPTABLES nor did your answer explain iptables nor is the OP using iptables. S/he is using vbox and thre is no need to make the situation any more complex then it is already.

Comment: Exactly! He is asking (and I'm quoting here) "The server has to access the internet on its own, while the clients have to access the internet across the server" and how he should setup the VB machines to do it.

Comment: And one uses the Vbox networking tool to do so, it is graphical and rather trivial. Perhaps you need a little experience with vbox or you need to read the vbox networking page.

Comment: OK. Whatever works for you! :)