# VirtualBox Choosing a network adapter type

Tags: networking, virtualbox, adapter

This question is not the same as [Which type of VirtualBox networking should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95022/which-type-of-virtualbox-networking-should-i-use)

Under advanced in the VirtualBox network settings you can choose between multiple adapter types:

- PCnet-PCI II (Am79C970A)
- PCnet-FAST III (Am79C973)
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
- Intel PRO/1000 T Server (82543GC)
- Intel PRO/1000 MT Server (82545EM)
- Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net)

According to the [manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html), the adapter you use depends on the OS that you are virtualizing.

Therefore, which one should I be using on a desktop machine running Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of adapter is determined by VirtualBox based on compatibility of the guest OS.

In my own case, I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 Desktop as host, and Windows 10 as guest. VirtualBox chose the `Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop` adapter, and it's worked well.

In your case, if you plan to run Ubuntu 17.04 as guest OS, VirtualBox should select, by default, the `AMD PCNet FAST III` adapter.

Comment: I have Windows host and Linux Mint guest.  AMD PCNet FAST III is the fastest